# ¿Cómo leer un archivo externo JSON con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Acabo de salir del grado de DAM y me piden en una prueba para un trabajo que lea un JSON para luego trabajar con el en un blog de amantes de los animales. Mi intención es solamente que esta información del JSON me salga en un alert, trabajando en local (luego ya me enteraré como trabajarlo en WEB), pero recurro aquí porque me es imposible encontrar la manera. El código del JSON sigue esta estructura (aquí solo vienen dos objetos de cientos que hay). Os agradecería muchísimo si alguien puede ayudarme con esto:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5fbfe211d32e20623de48785",
    "name": {
      "given": "Irma",
      "surname": "Mendez"
    },
    "points": 28,
    "animals": [
      "cat",
      "horse",
      "elephant",
      "tiger",
      "gorilla"
    ],
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "id": "5fbfe211f360cb3058158a7c",
    "name": {
      "given": "Liliana",
      "surname": "Britt"
    },
"points": 93,
    "animals": [
      "tiger",
      "panda",
      "jaguar",
      "zebra",
      "horse",
      "gorilla",
      "lion",
      "bear",
      "elephant",
      "penguin",
      "cat",
      "kangaroo",
      "koala",
      "monkey",
      "dog"
    ],
    "isActive": true,
    "age": 21
]
```

Comment: Necesitas ejecutar una petición AJAX, de preferencia, con la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) y puedes ver algunos ejemplos de esta [API de pruebas](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/).

Comment: Google es tu amigo. https://qastack.mx/programming/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado, mediante un [mcve], explicando el código, el problema o error y el resultado esperado, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos